# PayPal Sandbox Transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I think I managed to execute a payment successfully. At least I didn't get an error.

But the Sandbox Transactions table doesn't show more than some URLs.

There is just a green checkmark under HTTP Stats and the URL column has:
/v1/payments/payment/PAY-SHDO5SI7HF8O8WWIFWUH/execute
in it. Transaction date has got the wrong format, but it is just 8 hours behind.

However, is there something wrong or where can I see what products were "purchased" and the the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I got an answer to my question.

The Dev Dashboard at 
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/sandbox/

doesn't show (anymore?) the details of the payments. Instead you can see the details of each payment at
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/home

I was wondering, because in this tutorial you can see the transactions table showed some helpful details
https://youtu.be/BD1dOWIABe0?t=1833